# Check if 2 records of different with different user_id exist in child table in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am making a chat system in laravel. My table structure is

thread (id, subject)
participants (id, thread_id, user_id)
messages (id, thread_id, body, file)

I have built relationships **" thread hasMany participants"**, **"thread hasMany messages"**

Now the scenario is:
Let's suppose there are two users with IDs 3 and 4.
I want to check if there is any thread that exists having both participants matching these two user IDs.

In the other words, I can say "If user 3 and user 4 are participants of any thread"

How do I make this query?

Comment: So you want to **select all thread_id where user_id is 3 and 4**?

Comment: Yes, I want to check if there such thread exists or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to determinate if exists any thread which has both of users you can use `whereHas` method which allow to querying relationship. e.g

```php
$userIds = [ 3, 4 ];
$exists = Thread::whereHas( 'participants', function ( $query ) use ( $userIds ) {
    $query->whereIn( 'user_id', $userIds )
}, '>=', count( $userIds ) )->exists();
```